# existence of a function whhich satisfies two conditions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following question please: I search whether there exists a function $u$ such that 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} u(x) =0 \ \mbox{and} \ \lim_{x \to 0^+} (u(x)+(x \ln(x)) u'(x)) \neq 0.
$$
Really I have no idea to solve this question. Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} (u(x)+(x \ln(x)) u'(x)) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} (u(x)) + \lim_{x\to 0^+} (x \ln(x)) \times \lim_{x\to 0^+} (u'(x)) $$
 Then we can rewrite $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} (x \ln(x)) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} (\frac{\ln(x)}{\frac{1}{x}})$$ and use l'Hospital's rule: $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} (\frac{\ln(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}(\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}(-x) = 0$$
So we have $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} (u(x)) + \lim_{x\to 0^+} (x \ln(x)) \times \lim_{x\to 0^+} (u'(x)) = 0 + 0 = 0$$
 So there is $\mathbf{no}$ such function that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} (u(x)+(x \ln(x)) u'(x)) = any\ other\  number.$$
   There could be functions that satisfy $\lim_{x\to 0^+} (u(x))=0$, but $\lim_{x\to 0^+} (u(x)+(x \ln(x)) u'(x)) = undefined$, because in that limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+} (u'(x)) = undefined$.

Comment: But for example, the function $u(x)= x \cos(\dfrac{1}{x^2})$ satisfies the conditions. I think that there is a problem in the answer. No?

Comment: But how does that function satisfy the conditions?

Comment: You are right, this function dosn't satisfy the conditions. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Always glad to help.

Comment: Why does $u' \to 0$?

Comment: I want to add that there could be functions that satisfy this property, but $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} (u(x)+(x \ln(x)) u'(x)) = undefined$$ , because the limit of the derivative of such function as x approaches 0 is undefined.